# How to test if an object is a collection which can accept .each() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to test if an object is a collection which can accept .each() in jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. If you're calling `.each()`, it can only be called against a jQuery object, which means it can always be called, even if the collection is empty. Are you really asking about `$.each()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try length

```
if($('.my_class').length > 1)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/QhFDN/

Answer (score 3):

Just test if the object possess `each`, or if it's an `object` :

```
if (obj) {
   if (typeof obj.each == 'function') {
      obj.each(function(i,e) { ... });
   } else if (typeof obj == 'object') {
      $.each(obj, function(i,e) { ... });
   } else {
      //alert("not a valid collection");
   }
} else {
   //alert("obj is null");
}
```

There's not much any needs to make more validation, `each` will handle the rest.

Comment: Your `if` is a little messed up.  There's no need to test obj.each for truthiness, but you might consider testing obj itself before ever dereferencing it.

Comment: `} else if (obj.length) {` What if `obj` is a function? Functions have a `.length` property too. `(function(a,b,c){}).length // 3` Or if `obj` is a valid collection, but `.length` is `0`, you'll get the `alert()` saying it isn't valid.

Comment: @patrick, true if `obj.length` is 0, the alert will trigger. Modifying the answer

Comment: @Malvolio, indeed! good spotting. changing it to `if (obj && ...)`

Comment: Hate to pick on you, but `typeof null == 'object' // true`. Though it is likely being fixed in the next version of ECMAScript, so in about 15 years we won't need to worry about it anymore. ;) There are a few other problems with doing a simple `typeof obj == 'object'` as well.

Comment: ...oops, you've got the `null` issue covered with `if(obj) {`

Comment: @patrick, yes :) the IF checks for null (as typeof null == 'object'` is true), and checking if `obj` is an object simply checks if it's not a numeric value or a function, or a string, etc. I believe this code sample is sufficient to cover about 99% of the use cases.

Comment: Yeah the only thing I can thing of is like `typeof new Number(1) == 'object'; // true`, but how often does that happen? +1 Since it covers most cases. Why can't it just be simple?!

Answer (score 3):

If it's a jQuery object, you can always use the `.each` method on it, even if there are no elements in it. If the jQuery object is empty it will just not enter the loop, so it's harmless to call `.each` on an empty jQuery object:

```
obj.each(function(){ ... });
```

If you want to check if there are any items in a jQuery object, you can use the `length` property.

```
if (obj.length > 0) {
  ...
}
```

If you want to check if an object is an array, so that you can use it in the `$.each` method, you can use the `$.isArray` method:

```
if ($.isArray(obj)) {
  $.each(obj, function(index, value){ ... });
}
```

You can use `$.each` to loop the properties of any object. You can use the `isEmptyObject` to check if there are any properties:

```
if (!$.isEmptyObject(obj)) {
  $.each(obj, function(key, value){ ... });
}
```

You can use the `isPlainObject` method to determine if an object is created using `new Object()` or an object literal `{ ... }`:

```
if ($.isPlainObject(obj)) {
  $.each(obj, function(key, value){ ... });
}
```