# Checking whether something is iterable

Tags: javascript

In the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

The `for...of` construct is described to be able to iterate over "iterable" objects. But is there a good way of deciding whether an object is iterable?

I've tried to find common properties for arrays, iterators and generators, but have been unable to do so.

Aside from doing a `for ... of` in a try block and checking for type errors, is there a clean way of doing this?

Comment: Surely, as the author, you know if your object is iterable?

Comment: The object is passed as an argument, I'm not certain.

Comment: Right but I mean you will know what the type of object is returned?

Comment: Might be a probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069316/how-to-test-if-an-object-is-a-collection-which-can-accept-each-in-jquery

Comment: Why not test the argument's typeof?

Comment: @andrew-buchan, James Bruckner: Checking for types may work, but if you read the MDN docs, you will notice that it says "array-like". I don't know what this means, exactly, hence the question.

Comment: Do `arguments` and `NodeList` count as iterables?

Comment: `arguments` is not, but `NodeList` is.

Comment: That was the first thing I did before asking this question, it doesn't work for arrays.

Comment: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:iterators states "*An object is iterable if it has an `iterator()` method.*". Yet, since this is a draft only a check might be implemenatation-dependent. What environment do you use?

Comment: Array-like === Iterable
Spread Operator === Iterable
Rest Params === Iterable

Object !== Iterable

You can convert between types if needed. Here is a handy URL to learn more about the Iterable and Iterator protocols in ES6 (I'm still learning too, which is what brought me here).

MDN had this handy info:
Built-in iterables

String, Array, TypedArray, Map and Set are all built-in iterables, because the prototype objects of them all have a Symbol.iterator method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the technical definition of a Javascript iterable and how do you test for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41559125/1048572)

Answer (score 251, accepted):

The proper way to check for iterability is as follows:

```
function isIterable(obj) {
  // checks for null and undefined
  if (obj == null) {
    return false;
  }
  return typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
}
```

Why this works (iterable protocol in depth): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Since we are talking about for..of, I assume, we are in ES6 mindset.

Also, don't be surprised that this function returns `true` if `obj` is a string, as strings iterate over their characters.

Comment: or, `Symbol.iterator in Object(obj)`.

Comment: There is (at least) one exception to using 'in' operator: string. String is iterable (in terms of for..of) but you cannot use 'in' on it. If not for this, I'd prefer using 'in' it looks definitely nicer.

Comment: shouldn't it be `return typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'`? "In order to be iterable, an object must implement the @@iterator method" – it specifies method

Comment: There is no proper semantics for  obj[Symbol.iterator] being anything else than (undefined or) function. If anyone put for example String there, it's a bad thing and IMO it's good if the code fails as soon as possible.

Comment: Would `typeof Object(obj)[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'` work in all cases?

Comment: Should this check up the prototype chain ? In order to be iterable, an object must implement the @@iterator method, meaning that the object (or one of the objects up its prototype chain) must have a property with a Symbol.iterator key: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: `return obj && typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'`
In my case, `obj` won't be a string and if it is I don't want to iterate over it anyway.

Comment: @TatzyXY could you please provide more info, why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @TomasKulich In IE 11 `typeof obj[Symbol.iterator]` is not a function. There is just the object saved and not a function. Thats the reason why this code does not work  in IE 11.

Comment: @TatzyXY Symbols are not (fully) implmented in IE. Are you including babel-polyfill (or some other polyfill that'd do the job) ? Try including for example this: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.0.0/polyfill.js
and it should work.

Comment: Always gotta love Javascript and its magic strings..

Comment: In more recent versions of Javascript, you can just do this: `typeof obj?.[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'`, or just `!!obj?.[Symbol.iterator]` if you don't care about the function test.

Answer (score 70):

```
if (Symbol.iterator in Object(value)) {

}
```

[`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object) will box anything which isn't an object into one. This prevents the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator from throwing exceptions and removes the need to check for edge cases. `null` and `undefined` become empty objects, and the condition evaluates to `true` for a string, array, Map, Set, and so on.

Alternatively, in an environment that supports [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
if (value?.[Symbol.iterator]) {

}
```

The `?.` syntax causes `null` and `undefined` to be ignored, and property access is safe on all other value types. This might not read like English, but checking the truthiness of a property to assert its existence is fairly idiomatic.

I would personally recommend inlining this code instead of defining a function, as it is relatively short and less ambiguous than a call to some `isIterable(x)` function.

---

Keep in mind that the word *iterable* specifically refers to the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol), though there exist different ways to loop over objects. The following list is not exhaustive:

- [`arr.forEach(func)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) runs a function on each non-empty slot in an array (see sparse arrays [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#sparse_arrays)).
- You can [*enumerate*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) certain keys of an object with `for ... in`
- Some collections have [`.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys), [`.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values) and [`.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) methods that return iterators.
- [`Object.keys(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or [`Object.entries(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) return arrays made from an object's properties, which you can then iterate on.

Answer (score 33):

Why so verbose?

```
const isIterable = object =>
  object != null && typeof object[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'
```

Comment: `Readability > Cleverness` always returns `true`.

Comment: Haha, normally I'm the one to complain about unreadable code, but actually I think this is pretty readable. Like an english sentence: If the object is not null and the symbolic iterator property is a function, then it is iterable. If that's not dead simple, I don't know what is ...

Comment: imo, the point of "readability" is to understand what's happening without _actual_ reading

Comment: @Alexander Mills Your improvement made the code worse. 1. Like @jfmercer said `Readability > Cleverness`, so shortening the variable `object` to `o` helps nobody. 2. An empty string `''` is iterable and so it must return `true`.

Comment: Got it, I figured there was a reason why it was using `!= null`

Comment: Maybe, the only thing you need to read is the name: `isIterable`.

Comment: Using `object` as the argument name here isn't quite right because the check works for more than just objects. Better to use something generic, like `x` or `value`.Other than that, in 2021 this actually feels the most readable to me. Funny how our perceptions about readability change.

Answer (score 23):

## 2022 Answer

If you are asking "Is `foo` iterable" then you probably come from a language (PHP, Python) where that question has a single answer. **In modern Javascript, there are different types of iterable.** Therefore, you have to check the ability to iterate depending on what you want to do with the variable.

## TL;DR

- Test the ability to iterate using `forEach()` with `!!foo.forEach`, returns true on an Array.
- Test the ability to iterate using `for..of` with `!!foo[Symbol.iterator]`, returns true on an Array or String.
- Test the ability to iterate using `for..in` with `!!Object.keys(Object(foo)).length`, returns true on an Array, String, or Object.

## Long answer

Let's define some variables:

```
const someNumber = 42;
42

const someArray = [1,2,3];
(3) [1, 2, 3]

const someString = "Hello";
"Hello, world!"

const someObject = {a:"A", b:"B"};
{a: "A", b: "B"}
```

### Testing iterability with `forEach()`

Which types can be iterated with `forEach()`, tested with `!!foo.forEach`:

```
someNumber.forEach(x=>console.log(x));
VM1526:1 Uncaught TypeError: someNumber.forEach is not a function at <anonymous>:1:12

someArray.forEach(x=>console.log(x));
VM916:1 1
VM916:1 2
VM916:1 3
undefined

someString.forEach(x=>console.log(x));
VM957:1 Uncaught TypeError: someString.forEach is not a function at <anonymous>:1:12

someObject.forEach(x=>console.log(x));
VM994:1 Uncaught TypeError: someObject.forEach is not a function at <anonymous>:1:12
```

Only the **Array** seems to be iterable with `forEach()`.

### Testing iterability with `for..of`

Which types can be iterated with `for..of`, tested with `!!foo[Symbol.iterator]`:

```
for (x of someNumber) { console.log(x); }
VM21027:1 Uncaught TypeError: someNumber is not iterable at <anonymous>:1:11
    
for (x of someArray) { console.log(x); }
VM21047:1 1
VM21047:1 2
VM21047:1 3
undefined

for (x of someString) { console.log(x); }
VM21065:1 H
VM21065:1 e
VM21065:1 l
VM21065:1 l
VM21065:1 o
undefined

for (x of someObject) { console.log(x); }
VM21085:1 Uncaught TypeError: someObject is not iterable at <anonymous>:1:11
```

​The **Array and String** seem to be iterable with for..of, but the Object is not. And both the Number and the Object threw an error.

### Testing iterability with `for..in`

Which types can be iterated with `for..in`, tested with `!!Object.keys(Object(foo)).length`:

```
for (x in someNumber) { console.log(x); }
undefined

for (x in someArray) { console.log(x); }
VM20918:1 0
VM20918:1 1
VM20918:1 2
undefined

for (x in someString) { console.log(x); }
VM20945:1 0
VM20945:1 1
VM20945:1 2
VM20945:1 3
VM20945:1 4
undefined

for (x in someObject) { console.log(x); }
VM20972:1 a
VM20972:1 b
undefined
```

​The **Array, String, and Object** all seem to be iterable with `for..in`. And though it did not iterate, the Number did not throw an error.

In modern, ES6 Javascript I see `forEach` used far more often than `for..in` or `for..of`. But Javascript developers must be aware of the differences between the three approaches, and the different behaviour of each approach.

Answer (score 11):

As a sidenote, **BEWARE** about the definition of **iterable**. If you're coming from other languages you would expect that something you can iterate over with, say, a `for` loop is **iterable**. I'm afraid that's not the case here where **iterable** means something that implements the [iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

To make things clearer all examples above return `false` on this object `{a: 1, b: 2}` because that object does not implement the iteration protocol. So you won't be able to iterate over it with a `for...of` **BUT** you still can with a `for...in`.

So if you want to avoid painful mistakes make your code more specific by renaming your method as shown below:

```
/**
 * @param variable
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
const hasIterationProtocol = variable =>
    variable !== null && Symbol.iterator in Object(variable);
```

Comment: You are making no sense. Why do you think it would break with `undefined`?

Comment: @adius I think I wrongly assumed you were doing `object !== null` in your answer but you're doing `object != null` so it's not breaking with `undefined` in that specific case. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I see. Btw: Your code is incorrect. `hasIterationProtocol('')` must return `true`! How about you remove your code and just leave the iterable explanation section, which is the only thing that adds real value / something new in your answer.

Comment: It does return `true`, by removing part of the old answer I merged both functions and forgot about the strict comparison. Now I put back the original answer which was working fine.

Comment: I never would have thought of using `Object(...)`, nice catch. But in that case the null check is not needed.

Answer (score 8):

If the object has the property `Symbol.iterator` then it is iterable. Then we can simply check if `obj` is iterable like this

#### TypeScript

```
function isIterable(x: unknown): boolean {
  return !!x?.[Symbol.iterator];
}
```

Or as an arrow function

```
const isIterable = (x: unknown): boolean => !!x?.[Symbol.iterator];
```

#### JavaScript

```js
const isIterable = x => !!x?.[Symbol.iterator];
```

### Examples

```js
isIterable(["hello", "world"]); // true
isIterable({}); // false
isIterable(null); // false
isIterable(undefined); // false
isIterable(1); // false
isIterable(true); // false
isIterable(Symbol("foo")); // false
isIterable(new Set()); // true
isIterable(new Map()); // true
```

Answer (score 7):

For **async** iterators you should check for the 'Symbol.asyncIterator' instead of 'Symbol.iterator':

```
async function* doSomething(i) {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
}

let obj = doSomething();

console.log(typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function');      // false
console.log(typeof obj[Symbol.asyncIterator] === 'function'); // true
```

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, as already stated, to test if `obj` is iterable just do

```
obj != null && typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'
```

### Historical answer (no more valid)

The [`for..of`](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements) construct is part of the ECMASCript 6th edition Language Specification Draft. So it could change before the final version.

In this draft, [iterable](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-iterable-interface) objects must have the function `iterator` as a property.

You can the check if an object is iterable like this:

```
function isIterable(obj){
   if(obj === undefined || obj === null){
      return false;
   }
   return obj.iterator !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: The iterator property was a temporary firefox thing. It's not ES6 compliant.
see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Iterator_property_and_iterator_symbol

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to check in fact if a variable is an object (`{key: value}`) or an array (`[value, value]`), you could do that:

```
const isArray = function (a) {
    return Array.isArray(a);
};

const isObject = function (o) {
    return o === Object(o) && !isArray(o) && typeof o !== 'function';
};

function isIterable(variable) {
    return isArray(variable) || isObject(variable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a check for `for ... in` and decided on the following.

```
isIterable (value) {
  // add further checks here based on need.
  return Object.keys(Object(value)).length > 0
}
```

This will return `true` for anything that is iterable and has at least one value.
Therefore empty strings, empty arrays, empty objects etc. will return `false`.
But `{a: 'x', b:'y'}` will return `true`.