# Can I use destructuring assignment with immutable.js?

Tags: immutable.js, destructuring

With standard JS objects, one can use destructuring assignment such as:

```
let obj = {name: 'james', code: '007'}
let {name, code} = obj // creates new variables 'name' and 'code' (with the proper values)
```

As suggested by some Flux / Redux evangelist, I use immutable.js for my app; can I use destructuring also on immutable List / Map? Of course, one could do:

```
let obj = immutable.fromJS({name: 'james', code: '007'})
let {name, code} = obj.toJS()
```

but this seems to have quite inefficient as the objects grow bigger (because the object needs to be deeply jsified first).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

With immutable List, the destructuring works quite straightforwardly. This is because destructuring of Arrays works on every iterable ([Checking whether something is iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884249/checking-whether-something-is-iterable)) and is not subjected just to js Arrays.

With Map, the situation is more complicated. Unlike with List, the destructuring of Map-like structures IS subjected just to plain JS objects and nothing more. Currently, it does not seem that ES community considers this a good idea (see https://esdiscuss.org/topic/extensible-destructuring-proposal)

However, there exist babel-plugin that enables this: https://github.com/vacuumlabs/babel-plugin-extensible-destructuring 
Having this plugin installed and enabled in .babelrc, you can simply patch immutable Map to have a `.@@get` method defined:

```
// main.js, first file loaded
import {Iterable} from 'immutable';
Iterable.prototype[Symbol.for('get')] = function(value) {return this.get(value); };
```

and everything works (also nested destructuring, or destructuring with default values)

```
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';
const map = fromJS({author: {name: {first: "John", last: "Doe"}, birthdate: "10-10-2010"}});
const {author: {name: {first, last}, birthdate}} = map;
```

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of the plugin mentioned above.