# How does ImmutableJS work with Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, immutable.js

I've been using ImmutableJS with Angular 2 for some time, because of it's performance benefits in change detection. See [here.](http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2)

However, I'm not quite sure, why Immutable works with Angular 2 by default. How does it know how to iterate over the values and display them, when there's no explicit array? Does it just call `toJS()` every time it accesses the values of the collection? Does it implement some kind of method that Angular 2 automatically calls?

And if so, is there a way to define your own collections which also implement this method?

An example:

```
Component({
    selector: 'list',
    template: '<ul><li *ngFor="#item of items">{{ item.id }}</li></ul>',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SiteComponent { 
    items: Immutable.List<Item>;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an Angular user, but I think it's quite easy to see what happens underneath: I'd assume that

```
ngFor="#item of items"
```

is transformed to some equivalent of `for..of` cycle. This construct can be used for iterating over Arrays, but also can be used with any iterable in general. (And yes, `immutable.List` correctly implements iterable protocol)

**Some fine resources:**

iterable protocol on SO:

[Checking whether something is iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884249/checking-whether-something-is-iterable/32538867#32538867)

iterable protocol in depth:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

**Finally:**

If you want to be 100% sure, create a simple structure that is iterable, but it's neither `Array` nor `Immutable.List`, so Angular cannot know how to iterate it but to use iterable protocol (requires `babel` or new version of `node`) :

```
'use strict'
let obj = {}
// obj is iterable with values 1, 2, 3
obj[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  console.log('Yes, I am using the iterable protocol indeed')
  return [1, 2, 3][Symbol.iterator]()
}
for (let i of obj) {
  console.log(i)  // prints 1, 2, 3
}
```

Now if you use this structure instead of `immutable.List`, you can easily see that the iterator is called.