# Nested for loops and multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to get my head around how nested for loops work with multidimensional arrays in JavaScipt and I'm a bit stuck on one point.
Using a stock example

```
var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

This outputs 1 2 3 4 5 6 which is what I expected.
However if I add numbers to the end of the outer array:

```
var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], 7, 8];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

I still get the same output of 1 2 3 4 5 6 ? ? 
I am confused why 7 & 8 are not being picked up by the loop. Interestingly, if I use strings instead:

```
var arr = [["a","b"], ["c","d"], "y", "z"];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

The output is a b c d y z, which is what I expected. Why does it behave differently for strings?

Comment: You loop looks for the elements of an arrays within an array. 7 and 8 on their own are not arrays. You neet to add brackets, either `var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7, 8]];` or `var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7, 0], [8, 0]];`

Comment: mmm good question btw on the letter part

Comment: gonna look into that also

Comment: jow I got it if you have a string and call the zero index on it it returns itself

Comment: it wont return itself. you can do this: `var str = 'willem'` and then `console.log(str[4])` and you will log an `e` into the console. If you specify an index on a string, every character get its own index key and you return that character. Your code wouldnt give you the expected result if it was names for example, e.g: `[['Joe', 'Jane'], ['Patrick', 'Sean', 'Julia', 'Willem']]`

Comment: Thanks for all the prompt and helpful answers. It will probably take me a little time to absorb this info. So, to clarify that I'm on the right track:
(A) 
Using the nested loop means the code is only looking for nested arrays which is why if I use a single loop on this array everything is logged from the outer array level as expected [1,2] [3,4] [5,6] 7 8.
(B) 
It works with the strings because they are "iterable" and the length property can be applied to them (i.e they can be indexed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how things look like in modern Javascript.

In respect to loops, all values can be divided into "iterable" and "non-iterable". Iterable are values that you can well... iterate - with the `for..of` loop.

```
for (let item of someIterableThing)
    // use item
```

(You *do not* use bare `for` loops - `for(var i...i < length)` - for the iteration, because not every iterable has `length` and indexes.)

Conversely, if you do `for...of` with a non-iterable thing, you'll get an error.

Arrays and strings are examples of iterable values, numbers are non-iterable. So when you have

```
[ [1,2], [3,4], "foobar" ]
```

all items in this array are iterable and your nested loop will work. However, in

```
[ [1,2], [3,4], 999]
```

the last item is non-iterable, and the nested loop will fail.

There's no built-in way to tell if an unknown value is iterable, you have to write a function for this:

```
 let isIterable = x => x && x[Symbol.iterator]
```

(see [the dedicated topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884249/checking-whether-something-is-iterable)).

Then, you can use the nested loop in a safe manner:

```
for (let item of array)
    if (isIterable(item))
        for (let subItem of item)
            console.log(subItem)
    else
        console.log(item)
```

As a side note, there are lots of obsolete information about Javascript on the net. The language is evolving, and things that were fine 5 years ago, are considered bad practice nowadays. Unfortunately, most tutorials, books and teachers do not keep up, and still promote old practices, like using bare `for` loops.

(Since people asked why exactly bare `for` loops are bad, consider this example:

You have an array `text` containing strings and multiple functions that process this array. Programmer A writes these functions in the old-fashioned manner:

```
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)  
     do_something_with(text[i]) // ;(
```

Programmer B writes them in the modern way:

```
for (let str of text)  
     do_something_with(str) // :)
```

Now, the `text` grows bigger and bigger and doesn't fit in memory anymore. So the system architect decided to replace it with a streamable file object that only yields one string at a time. Programmer A now has to rewrite all his 100 functions to adapt to the new interface:

```
  for (var file = TextFile; !file.eof(); file.getNext())
      do_something_with(file.currentLine)
```

which involves lots of pain, convulsions and headache.

Programmer B just enjoys her vacation.)

Comment: Bare `for` is faster than syntax-sweet `for ... of` ([benchmark is here](https://jsperf.com/for-of-vs-for-loop)).

Comment: @KoshVery: unless you write 3D games in Javascript, you don't care about microseconds.

Comment: while I can make it faster, I will.

Comment: @KoshVery: up to you, I prefer to keep my code clean.

Comment: Discouraging the use of plain for loops here is unfounded and not helpful. Neither is the introduction to for...of loops (at least not for this question)

Comment: @TinyGiant: yep, I feel your pain. Giving up something you learned 5-10 years ago and considered the right way all that time is not easy... but that's IT for you - things are changing fast and you have to keep up.

Comment: There is absolutely 0 reason to discourage the use of plain for loops though. There are often alternatives which may or may not be better for some intent or purpose, but there's nothing inherently bad about using plain for loops. Let alone the fact that using and understanding them is fundamental to understanding the language.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I added some explanations to the post.

Comment: Yeah, you're still wrong, and that is still completely unhelpful for this question.

Comment: @TinyGiant: well, your "not helpful" isn't very helpful either. ;) I hope you're just having a bad day. See you around!

Comment: I'm actually having a great day.  I just dislike seeing people discouraging the use of basic language constructs needlessly. You have yet to prove that for loops are inherently bad, and your edge case is irrelevant at best. You should use the best tool for the job, if that happens to be a plain for loop there is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, your inner loop is all about iterating the arrays found in the top level (non-nested array). It makes the assumption that all the elements in the top-level array will be nested arrays, which isn't the case. (You need to make sure that you have an array before attempting to iterate through it.) Since `7` and `8` in the top level aren't arrays, `arr[i].length` returns `undefined` for numbers, but strings are "array like" objects and do have a `length` property. A string of `"y"` has a `length` of `1` and so the inner loop works because it starts from zero and obtains the character at position zero in the string "array" of `"y"`, which is `"y"`.

But, this is a good reason not to use traditional `for` loops with arrays when we now have **[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**, which eliminates the need for indexes to be manually managed and allows us to access the value being enumerated directly without worrying about indexes.

```js
var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], 7, 8];
var output = "";

// Enumerate the top-level array:
arr.forEach(function(value){
  // Check to see if the item is an array
  if(value instanceof Array){
    // If so, enuerate that nested array
    value.forEach(function(nestedValue){
      // Add the nested array's value to the output
      output += nestedValue + " " ;
    });
  } else {
    // Item is not an array, just add its value to the output
    output += value + " ";
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Oh, and by the way, I realize that this is not what you were asking about, but just as an FYI, here's a way to obtain all the values without any loops:

```js
console.log([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], 7, 8].toString().split(",").join(" "));
```

Answer (score 2):

`String`, `Array`, `TypedArray`, `Map` and `Set` are all [built-in iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Iterable_examples), because each of their prototype objects implements an `@@iterator` method. While `Number` is not iterable:

```js
const iterate = v => {
  for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) console.log(v[i])
}

iterate([1, 'two', 777]) // iterates by element
iterate('abc') // iterates by symbol
iterate(123) // does not iterate
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a double loop. When you are doing the statement `console.log(arr[i][j]);` you try first to go into the index i of the `arr` array in this part `arr[i]`.

You then proceed to call the index of the value in the array with `[j]`. Because 7, and 8 are just numbers and not arrays they don't log.

This is the reason why the letters are logged:

```js
 var arr = [["a","b"], ["c","d"], "y", "z"];
 for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
/*   console.log(arr[i][j]);  */
  }
}

var foo = "a";
var bar = foo[0];

console.log(bar);
```

Strings behave as arrays of characters that's why you get the letter returns itself  when you call foo[0] it returns a.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it behave differently for strings?

Because strings are treated as an array of characters.

A JavaScript string stores a series of characters like "John Doe". Each character can be accessed using an array index, and also has `length` method for getting the size of the string. Hence why your `"y", "z"` works but not `7, 8` as they are not an array.