# How to avoid the castArray function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

This is no anything special about the [Lodash castArray](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#castArray) function. Is there any ways to solve this task without any external libraries, with the newest language features, but still shortly?

If you are not familiar with the task:

```
castArray(['abc', 'def'])
// ['abc', 'def']
```

```
castArray('abc')
// ['abc']
```

```
castArray()
// []
```

```
castArray(undefined)
// [undefined]
```

Is there way to do it without a type checking?
Notice that I look for the shortest equivalent, ES6+.

Comment: Click "source" in the link you posted.

Comment: You *changed* your requirement! The "without type checking" makes your question *quite* different and invalidates the current answer. That's [not good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271400/edits-that-do-not-change-the-meaning-of-the-original-post-but-invalidate-posted). The `castArray(undefined) // [undefined]` seems fine, though - it's a clarification that is already in the docs but not needed attention.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you'd even solve this without type checking. You *need* to do different stuff for an array and not an array.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I still look for short and convenient way to do this thing.

Answer (score 4):

You could take a function with a default value of an empty array and return the result of a check with either the array or a new one.

```js
const castArray = (data = []) => Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];

console.log(castArray(['abc', 'def']));  // ['abc', 'def']
console.log(castArray('abc'));           // ['abc']
console.log(castArray());                // []

console.log(castArray(1));               // => [1]
console.log(castArray({ 'a': 1 }));      // => [{ 'a': 1 }]
console.log(castArray('abc'));           // => ['abc']
console.log(castArray(null));            // => [null]
console.log(castArray(undefined));       // => [undefined]
console.log(castArray());                // => []

var array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(castArray(array) === array); // => true
```

Comment: Just added the examples from the page to show it performs the same as Lodash.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't for `castArray(undefined)`. Didn't notice that - in that case it creates an empty array. OP can decide whether that's acceptable or not but it's relatively easy to amend.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer doesn't take in account NodeLists and other Array-like (Iterrable) objects.

A more accurate answer to castArray would be

```js
function isIterable(value) {
       return Symbol.iterator in Object(value)
}

function getElementsAsArray(obj) {
    if (!obj) {
        return []
    }

    if (isIterable(obj) && typeof obj !== 'string') {
        return Array.from(obj)
    }

    return [obj]
}
```

(checking for iterable is from here [Checking whether something is iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884249/checking-whether-something-is-iterable))