# How can I check whether an object is iterable statically?

Tags: typescript, iterable

I have a function which needs an iterable:

```
function fn(ary) {
    for (let value of ary)
        console.log(value)
}
```

In javascript, I would take advantage of [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols):

> ```js
> function isIterable(obj) {
>     // checks for null and undefined
>     if (obj == null) {
>         return false;
>     }
>     return typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
> }
> ```

<sup>Taken from [Tomas Kulich original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32538867/6320039).</sup>

which would lead to the next code:

```
function fn(ary) {
    if (!isIterable(ary)) throw 'Not iterable'

    for (let value of ary)
        console.log(value)
}
```

Isn't there a way to take advantage of TypeScript's typing facilities rather than using this on-the-fly function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking whether something is iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884249/checking-whether-something-is-iterable)

Comment: This question is identical to the one you linked — you should just post the answer over there.

Comment: @jhpratt — It really is not, the referred question is about **dynamic** check in **Javascript** and mine is about **static** check in **TypeScript**. Actually, I wrote _because_ I didn't see the typescript version, and the documentation was no straight to the point. My intent is for some googler to quickly find a TypeScript solution for this issue. If you were confused, I'd invite you to edit. I don't have any idea to clarify my question further (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [`Iterable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#iterables) type that would do just that:

```
function fn(ary: Iterable<any>) {
    for (let value of ary)
        console.log(value)
}
```

<sup>[Corresponding TypeScript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKAhgJwJ4C5ECSUAppugEYA2xAPOmNgHwCUiA3gFCLfJyaKpqURADd0lEMURxgiLNmZce3CAgDOcagDpKcAOaoxE4ooC+HDilQBGVgHo7iAGLoYlNYlUBbAA5v0sAiWaADa1gC69o4A8gDSQA).</sup>

Note that `Iterable` requires on type argument. `any` allows you to specifically detect *just* if an object is iterable, although you could go further and specify on what you would like to iterate (eg. `Iterable<Number>`).