# Firebase cloud functions: undefined is not a function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to convert a map to an array with a firebase cloud functions

This is my code.

```
  let map = new Map();
  map.set("1", 1);
  map.set("2", 2);
  console.log(new Array(...map).map(pairs => pairs[0]));

  // Upper code not relevant: just to test, but prints ["1", "2"] in the firebase logs)


  const getUser = await admin.firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .doc(context.auth.uid)
  .get();

  let userMap = getUser.data()['friendsMap'];
  console.log(userMap);

   // Prints this in the firebase logs: { '1234ab': 'Jeff',
  5678ab: 'Bob' }


  let userIDLIST = new Array(...userMap).map(pairs => pairs[0]);

  console.log('userIDLIST:'+userIDLIST);
```

when I want to convert the userMap to userIDLIST array (last lines of code), I get the error:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to exactly say what is your problem based on the error you get (which is not really meaningful! :-) ) but it is probably caused by the fact that `userMap` is not an iterable.

As you will read in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (Section "Only for iterables" at the bottom of the page):

> Spread syntax (other than in the case of spread properties) can be applied only to iterable objects.

You can check that `userMap` is not an iterable with the function you will find in the following SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32538867/3371862).

The reason is that the Map type in Firestore "represents an **object** embedded within a document" (as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types?authuser=1) on data Types) and this Object is actually not a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) *stricto sensu*, but *simply* an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

As explained in the Map [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (Section "Objects vs. Maps"):

> Object is similar to Map: both let you set keys to values, retrieve
>   those values, delete keys, and detect whether something is stored at a
>   key. For this reason (and because there were no built- in
>   alternatives), Objects have been used as Maps historically.
>
> However, there are important differences that make Map preferable in
>   certain cases:
>
> .....
>
> - A Map is an iterable, so it can be directly iterated
> - Iterating over an Object requires obtaining its keys in some fashion and iterating over them.

You can check that `userMap` is actually not a Map by doing

```
console.log(userMap instanceof Map);   //  -> False
```

---

So, using `Object.entries()` as follows should solve the problem:

```
  const getUser = await admin.firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .doc(context.auth.uid)
  .get();

  const userFriendsMap = getUser.data().friendsMap;
  const userFriendsArray = Object.entries(userMap);

  const userIDLIST = new Array(...userFriendsArray).map(pairs => pairs[0]);
```