# Can typeof return a falsey value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeof

I stumbled over some interesting code inside react.
[Link to code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/553440bd1578ef71982c4a10e2cc8c462f33d9be/packages/react-devtools-shared/src/hydration.js#L246)

```
if (typeof data[Symbol.iterator]) { ... }
```

In my understanding `typeof[data[Symbol.iterator]]` should be truthy because typeof returns a string.
like:

```
const obj = {}
if(typeof(obj.x)){
  console.log("hello world");
}
```

gives out “hello world” because even typeof(undefined) => "undefined" => truthy

tldr: Is there any possible falsey outcome of typeof?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof Reading through this documentation shows there to be no way of returning a false outcome. Closest thing to it is it returning 'undefined'.

Comment: if you are checking if object is iterable.. you would be doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884249/checking-whether-something-is-iterable

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) :

> **Errors**
> Before ECMAScript 2015, typeof was always guaranteed to return
> a string for any operand it was supplied with. Even with undeclared
> identifiers, typeof will return 'undefined'. Using typeof could never
> generate an error.
>
> But with the addition of block-scoped let and Statements/const using
> typeof on let and const variables (or using typeof on a class) in a
> block before they are declared will throw a ReferenceError. Block
> scoped variables are in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the
> block until the initialization is processed, during which, it will
> throw an error if accessed.

```
typeof undeclaredVariable === 'undefined';

typeof newLetVariable; // ReferenceError
typeof newConstVariable; // ReferenceError
typeof newClass; // ReferenceError

let newLetVariable;
const newConstVariable = 'hello';
class newClass{};
```

In general, `typeof()` will return a string and thus if checked in a condition alone will always be truthy. If you want to check a variable and verify if its undefined (or any other state), you can use a condition like : `typeof(undefinedvariable) == "undefined"`

Comment: can you explain how temporal dead zones apply here? if typeof itself throws error.. how would `if (typeof data[Symbol.iterator]) { ... }` be effective?

Comment: I cannot find any reason for such a condition, as typeof will always be true. It appears that this code was added to react repository 2 years ago in a [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/ce65df7092ed69b45aa5787b708c1516b2c07427) to **Add support for unserializable types (e.g. Set/Map, Immutable)**.

Comment: Yup, turns out the condition was indeed nonsensical. Thanks for your help! https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20905#issuecomment-788032294