# Is there a typescript type that stands for any iterable object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

We have a function such as below

```
export const objectUndefinedToNull = (obj) => {
  const apply = (o) => {
    Object.keys(o).forEach((key) => {
      const value = o[key];
      if (value === undefined) {
        o[key] = null;
      }
      if (value instanceof Array || value instanceof Object) {
        apply(value || {});
      }
    });
  };
  apply(obj);
  return obj;
};
```

I would like to replace all `any` and `unknown` types for more appropriate types.
Is there any type that stands for any iterable types such as an array or object that can be iterated?

Comment: Yes there is: `Iterable<T>`

Comment: @Silvermind, Thanks, i didn't know there is such a type for this, but it doesn't seem to fit in my case because i want to be able to pass something like `Record<string, someType>` or `{ [key: string]: someType }` on `objectUndefinedToNull` object and `Iterable<T>` has type mismatch to those mentioned types

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking whether something is iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884249/checking-whether-something-is-iterable)

Comment: not exactly, but i may be able to use it by rewriting the current function and just use type predicate or type guards to check for iterables

Comment: This code doesn't actually work for object types such as `Record<string, someType>` does it?   It's trying to set undefined object values to null, but `objectUndefinedToNull({ a: 1, b: undefined })` returns `{ 1: null, a: 1, b: undefined }`, which surely can't be what's intended.  It only works for arrays as far as I can see. `objectUndefinedToNull([1, undefined])` returns `[1, null]` which looks better.

Comment: @RichN , Yeah, thanks for noticing. I've already fixed the code snippet in the post.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a `IterableType` class as follows and then use that in place of `any` and `unknown`.

```
class IterableType<T> implements Iterable<T>, Record<K,T>
```

Alternatively, keep using `any` and `unknown` as per your original code, but add some type checking to the function to check that it is a valid type (Array, record, etc).

Comment: awesome, thanks for giving me an idea. I was currently playing around with this one and it seems like Typescript makes it hard to do so. Apparently, You have to implement your own `Symbol.iterator`