# Narrow down type in type guard; is Iterable but no string

Tags: typescript

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32538867/5767484) solution, I've created a type guard:

```js
const isNoStringIterable = (obj: any): obj is Iterable<any> => {
  if (obj == null) return false;
  else if (typeof obj === "string") return false; // this isn't properly reflected by the type guard
  else return typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === "function";
};
```

The main difference to the linked solution is that I want it to return `false` in case we have a `string`. Is there any way to narrow down the type guard declaration to something like "`obj is Iterable but no string`"?

Comment: Could you show how you intend to call `isNoStringIterable()`?  Depending on the use case and what you need to see happen when it returns `false` you might have different implementations.  [This version](https://tsplay.dev/W4jqvN) is generic and filters the input type if it's a union.  If that works for you I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz: Thanks for your response! As background: I wanted check the type of React `children` and planned to map them in case it's an `Iterable` but not a `string`. Meanwhile, I found out that I'm probably better off with `React.Children.toArray()`, but I created this question anyway out of curiosity. I'll gladly accept your solution as an answer, thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have *negated types* as implemented (but never merged/released) in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317), so there's no direct way to say `not string` and thus no direct way to say `Iterable<any> & not string`.  Instead we need to work around it by expressing "not" in some other fashion.

If your input type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), then you can filter it to include `Iterable<any>`-compatible members but exclude `string`-compatible members.  Union filtering isn't *exactly* the same as type negation, but it often serves the same purpose.

There are utility types like [`Extract<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) and [`Exclude<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) you can use to do this, but you also can write your own via a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) directly (which is how `Extract<T, U>` and `Exclude<T, U>` are implemented):

```
type NoStringIterable<T> =
  T extends string ? never : T extends Iterable<any> ? T : never;
```

You can test that this behaves as expected:

```
type Test = NoStringIterable<string | number[] | Set<boolean> | Date>;
// type Test = Set<boolean> | number[]
```

Both `Set<boolean>` and `number[]` are `Iterable<any>` and not `string`, so that's what comes out.  And now we can make `isNoStringIterable` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function where its input is of type `T` and its output is `obj is NoStringIterable<T>`:

```
const isNoStringIterable = <T,>(obj: T): obj is NoStringIterable<T> => {
  if (obj == null) return false;
  else if (typeof obj === "string") return false;
  else return typeof (obj as any)[Symbol.iterator] === "function";
};
```

Let's test it out:

```
function foo(obj: string | number[]) {
  if (isNoStringIterable(obj)) {
    obj.map(x => x + 1);
  } else {
    obj.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

Looks good.  The compiler narrows `string | number[]` to `number[]` in the `true` block and to `string` in the `false` block, as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gZWAJwJYDsDmBJYFkCGARgDYQA8AKgHxQC8AUFFJVBAB57oAmAzlLxQZMUAPxR0EAG74oALhZtOEHv1z5iZcgXQha41gskzkAbgYNQkFhEH1YiIVnWFSFQWixQAPhICuALZE+ADaALo+UAgQwOREcHBkOrS+ACIEeNTmAPTZUFbQlLbA9tGx8YkQyZHogcHI4RYAxnDodqi88EieOHiuZPZUADTUABRwRABWCpQAlAoTk1AdDt3CLpoUNPS0AN5MywBmUONT9HT+JCSzUMgxfsjoUIcEJLwQ5swQb9Cox6MFODHRbnC4AIg8wjBNzuwAeTxeP0+bB+t3uj3y4AgQJOIII-B0IFmIQQICCiQAdKg+hk4MgInRGVAwYc-OgmsBUK0weYAL7mBis9mc1rPBKnaYCJwiXy1IKhMI3fbMP4nDpdaUbNwS2ZKg7MRYUgIEMCjdg7KDmgDUUAAjLNkbyUe8oMrmFBDcA4ABVMCQZAAYXxEFGDoOvIYvKAA)